# Find all $f : \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(f(x+y)) = f(x+y) + f(x)f(y) -xy$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, contest-math, functional-equations

Find all $f : \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that

$$f(f(x+y)) = f(x+y) + f(x)f(y) -xy$$
for all reals $x,y.$ (Belarusian Mathematical Olympiad-1995)

My answer:

Consider $f(0) = c. ...(i)$

Let $x,y = 0$ at first.

$$f(f(x+y)) = f(x+y) + f(x)f(y) -xy$$
$$\implies f(f(0+0)) = f(0+0) + f(0)f(0) -0 \times 0$$
$$\implies f(f(0)) = f(0) + f(0)f(0) + 0$$
$$\implies f(c) = c + c \times c + 0$$
$$\implies f(c) = c + c^2$$
$$\implies f(c) - c = c^2 ...(ii)$$

Now, let $y = -x.$

Therefore,
$$f(f(x+y)) = f(x+y) + f(x)f(y) -xy$$
$$\implies f(f(x-x)) = f(x-x) + f(x)f(y) -(x\times -x)$$
$$\implies f(f(0)) = f(0) + f(x)f(-x) + x^2$$
$$\implies f(c) = c + f(x)f(-x) + x^2$$
$$\implies f(c)-c = f(x)f(-x) + x^2$$

From $..(ii),$

Therefore, $$c^2 = f(x)f(-x) + x^2$$

Now, let $x = c$

$$Therefore, c^2 = f(x)f(-x) + c^2$$
$$\implies c^2 - c^2 = f(c)f(-c)$$
$$\implies 0 = f(c)f(-c)$$

Hence,

$f(c) = 0 ...(iii)$

$f(-c) = 0 ...(iv)$

Multiplying $(i) and (iii),$
$$f(0) \times f(c) = c \times 0$$
$$\implies f(0) \times f(c) = 0$$
$$\implies f(0) = 0$$
$$\implies c = 0$$

Similarly, Multiplying $(i) and (iv)$

$\implies c = 0$

Hence $c = 0.$

But $f(c) = 0,$

Therefore, $f(c) = c$

I can't go further than that can anyone help me out.

Comment: If a product is 0 you only get at least one of the inputs is 0,  not both of them

Comment: which product is 0

Comment: ///your (iii) and (iv), you get one of them is true, then later you have $f(0)\times f(c)=0$ but since you assumed $f(c)=0$ you can't conclude anything about $f(0)$

Comment: How to show that c =0

Comment: solution in aops https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1231344p6224321

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(f(x+y))=f(x+y)+f(x)f(y)-xy$$

As mentioned above, I have assumed $f(0)=c$ for some real $c$.

- $(x,y)\equiv(c,-c)$
  $$f(c)=c+f(c)f(-c)+c^2$$
- $(x,y)\equiv(0,0)$
  $$f(c)=c+c^2$$
  The above equations imply that $f(c)f(-c)=0$. Hence, there exists some real $k$ such that $f(k)=0$.
- $(x,y)\equiv(k,0)$
  $$f(f(k+0))=f(k+0)+f(k)f(0)-k\cdot0\implies c=0\implies f(0)=0 $$
- $(x,y)\equiv(x,0)$
  $$f(f(x))=f(x)\implies f(f(x+y))=f(x+y)\implies f(x)=x\cdot \frac{y}{f(y)}$$
  If $f(x)=0$ for all real $x$, we have, $xy=0$ for all reals,which is a contradiction. Hence there exists some real $p$ such that $f(p)=q$ and $q\ne 0$.
- $(x,y)\equiv(x,p)$
  $$f(f(x+p))=f(x+p)\implies f\left((x+p)\cdot\frac{p}{q}\right)=(x+p)\cdot\frac{p}{q} \implies p=q$$
  Therefore, $\boxed{f(x)=x}$ for all real $x$. Substitute this back into the original F.E to verify the result.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your last final step? I understood your entire point except the last step.

Comment: We know that $f(x)=x\cdot\frac{y}{f(y)}$. Substitute $(x+p)\cdot \frac{p}{q}$ in the functional equation. You will arrive at $(x+p)\cdot \frac{p^2}{q^2}=(x+p)\cdot \frac{p}{q}$.

Comment: Basically, you know that $f(x)=x\cdot\frac{p}{q}$ for all real $x$. Now plug this into the original F.E and the result follows.

Comment: We know $f(x)f(y) = x\times y$ , as you have already showed it. Now let $x=x$ and  $y=p$. Therefore $f(x) = \frac{x \times p}{f(p)}$. But $f(p) = q$ as your solution shows. Therefore $f(x) = \frac{x\times p}{q}$. Also now, $f(f(x+y)) = f(x+y)$. putting $x = x$ and $y = 0$. $f(f(x)) = f(x)$. putting $f(x) = \frac{x\times p}{q}$ in the lhs. $f(\frac{x\times p}{q}) = f(x)$. So $p$ must be equal to $q$ or it is not posssible.

Comment: But $q$ is not a variable. You have proved $f(x)=x$ for some constant $q$, not for all reals. Also, my first comment seems to finish it off without much difficulty.

Comment: what about the upper one long result

Comment: how do you arrive at p = q from $f(\frac{(x+p).p}{q}) = \frac{(x+p).p}{q}$

Comment: Use $f(x)={x}\cdot\frac{p}{q}$. Substitute $(x+p)\cdot\frac{p}{q}$ in place of $x$.

Comment: Aha. got it at last thanks a lot

Comment: This is clearly not the only solution, as $f(x)=0$ trivially satisfies the equation.  Your problem was in assuming $xy=0$ is a contradiction,  when it isn't if $y=0$ everywhere

Comment: @Alan The equation, $xy = 0$, is not *always* true for *all* real $x$ *and* $y$. I believe that’s where the contradiction happens. Also, the zero function doesn’t satisfy the equation, since if you substitute $x = y = 1$, you would get $0 = -1$.

Comment: @Alan The only solution is $f(x)=x$ for all real $x$. $f(x)=0$ for all real $x$ is not a solution and is well explained by the above comment.  If everything is clear, I would also request you to take back the downvote :)

Comment: @Alan Am I still missing something?